# Swift app development (game w/ SpriteKit) I want some visual changes to appear on the screen and then disappear after a given period of time

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game using Swift and SpriteKit. I have written something of this sort:

```
node.alpha = 0
sleep(1)
node.alpha = 1
```

where *node* is an *SKSpriteNode*. Instead of making node invisible, freezing the running of the program for one second and making node visible again, what this code does is it simply freezes the running of the program for one second. I figured that all visual changes take place periodically, maybe after each update. How can resolve this and make the node disappear for one second, having the program frozen?

Thank you!

Comment: by creating a timer which fires after one second calling a method that does the `node.alpha = 1`

Comment: @J164 The main thread is where your app handles touch events (user input). App should be responsive and pausing a main thread like this, with sleep() function, is a very bad way to solve things. You should use something like KnightOfDragon has pointed in his answer. SKActions are meant for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is going to assume you want to just pause the scene, and not the entire program.

What you want to use is the SKActions  `sequence` and `waitForDuration`,

and the nodes `pause` variable.

You essentially want to move the entire scene into a separate node, and let another node control the pausing of it.

Set your scene nodes like this:

```
let sceneWorld = SKNode() //make this available to the entire class
let timerNode = SKNode()

...
override func didMoveToView()
{
    ....
    scene.addNode(timerNode)
    scene.addNode(sceneWorld)  //sceneWorld is where you will be adding all gfx sprites now
}

func pauseWorld()
{

  let wait1sec = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
  let unpause = SKAction.runBlock({sceneWorld.pause = false;showNodes(true)})

  timerNode.runAction(SKAction.sequence[wait1sec,unpause])      

  showNodes(false)
  sceneWorld.pause = true;

}

func showNodes(show : Boolean)
{
    let alpha = (show) : 1.0 ? 0.0
    //set all nodes that need to hide here with alpha
    ...
}
```

Comment: I fixed the problem using something else that was very convenient. Thanks guys

Comment: well what did you do,  don't leave questions unanswered

Comment: I put the sleep() in the update. Now the command to make the node transparent is executed in a separate update from sleep() and make it opaque. I had to change the whole design of a lot of things but it's much better now this way

Comment: @J164 using sleep is terrible way to program,  it is almost never needed in an object oriented environment,  and should only be used as a last resort when  designing

Answer (score 0):

The solution of luk2303 has worked perfectly for me in my apps.
you can create a timer like this:

```
node.alpha = 0
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "makeNodeVisible", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func makeNodeVisible(){
    node.alpha = 1
}
```

For some reason using the sleep function won't work in SpriteKit because it is meant for the ViewController or something like that.

Comment: You do not want to be using NSTimers for a scenario like this,  you want to keep your sprite contained to the scene world's state.  If the scene pauses, that means you need to keep track of all your timers and pause them as well.  If the scene's speed changes,  you would need to also account for that with the timer.

Comment: That's true but for a simple 1 second delay it isn't to bad to use a timer, because the change that it is important to pause the game in that 1 second is pretty small

Comment: A lot can go wrong with the timer,  your app can crash if you do not maintain it properly, and you will have a hard time debugging since it does not break at any line in code